# most efficient way to calculate with query requests

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset

I'm currently working on a Django app that calculates prices with hours input.
I have two models :

the first model calculates all the prices:

```
class Vacation(models.Model):
    version = models.ForeignKey(Version)
    field_1 = XXX
    ...
    field_n = XXX

    def prices(self):
        calculation = ....
        return [price_1, ... , price_n]
    def margin(self):
        calculation = ....
        return [margin_1, ... , margin_n]
```

And the second sums all the prices of the objects from Vacation(model)

```
class Version(models.Model):
    field1 = XXX
    ...
    field_n= XXX

    def totals(self):
        prix_tot = sum(vacation.prices()[0] for vacation in Vacation.objects.filter(version_contrat=self))
        marge_tot = sum(vacation.margin()[0] for vacation in Vacation.objects.filter(version_contrat=self))

    return [prix_tot, marge_tot]
```

So I found this ways of doing it but when I refresh the page it takes ages(about 25seconds vs 5 seconds without the query request)

Is there any other way of doing this ??

I've looked at Django aggregations , I might be wrong but I wasn't under the impression that it helped in my situation. Anyone has any idea of how to make this process more efficient ??

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: I'm not sure how you expect us to know whether aggregations could help when you've edited out all the specifics about what those methods are doing.

Comment: What is version_contrat? You don't seem to have a field like that anywhere in your code.